# if product is in cart add class to add to cart button in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on woocommerce project and I want to add a new class on Add to Cart button if product is already added in cart, Can you help me to find out with this.

I'm changing right now using this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'bbloomer_custom_add_cart_button_single_product' ); 
function bbloomer_custom_add_cart_button_single_product( $label ) {

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $product = $values['data'];
    if( get_the_ID() == $product->get_id() ) {
        $label = __('Added', 'woocommerce');
    }
}

return $label; }
```

text is changing but I want add class so I can add my css style

please help Thank You

Comment: You need to [**override some Woocommerce templates via the theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) … Those templates are located in `"templates/single-product/add-to-cart/"` depending on your product type... As explained in the linked documentation, you need first to copy them to your active child theme (or active theme)… Then you will have to insert your code in each, to add a custom class when products are in cart.

Comment: Hi I did this Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The add to cart template which is in `woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php` has a filter. So we can also over write the class using `add_filter` function in `functions.php`.

```
function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_class ( $html, $product, $args ) {
    // Define the classes to be added
    $class_to_append = "this_guys_in_cart";

    // Check if product is in cart
    $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) );

    if ( $in_cart != '' ) {
        // Append the extra class
        $args['class'] = $args['class']." {$class_to_append}";

        $html = sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
            esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
            isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );
    }

    // Return Add to cart button
    return $html;
}

add_filter( "woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link", "woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_class", 10, 3 );
```

> **Note:** This method is not recommended if `add-to-cart.php` filte is modified in theme templates